# how to change document title on custom template file

Tags: php, wordpress

i have created a custom template file in my wordpress child theme. is there a way i can set the document/page title tag in each template file i create?

i have tried adding the below in my child theme `functions.php` file

```
function NewTitle() {
    return 'testing';
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'NewTitle', 10, 2 );
```

but this just keeps the title the same as what is in the wordpress site settings

i have also tried adding this code in my custom template file above `get_header();`

what is the correct code needed to change the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WordPress filters (1) take an argument, (2) return a modified version of it. You're missing #1:

```
function NewTitle($title, $sep) {
    return 'testing';
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'NewTitle', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thats not working and its stopping the full page from displaying (probably has an error)

Comment: There's no error in my code above. Please read the error message to determine where the problem is.

Comment: The `wp_title` filter is used to filter the title of the page (called with `wp_title()`). This filters the text appearing in the HTML `<title>` tag, and should be placed in *functions.php*. Are you wanting to change the visible page title? Or the `<title></title>` tag contents?

Comment: i want to change the <title> tag contents

Comment: yeah i am, functions.php in my theme

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code in the **functions.php** of your theme.

```
add_filter('the_title','some_callback');
function some_callback(){
     if ( is_page_template( 'about.php' ) ) { // check current template name
          return 'your title';
     }
     return;
}
```